# How to force an error in PowerShell query

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-remoting

I have a files that have a name like this in my SP site. I'm just wondering how can I prevent downloading an empty blank file is there is no file that have a current date.

Currently if I add +5 in AddDays then it download an empty file. I'm just wondering how to make it not download anything at all if the file didn't exist.

```
Full-Report-2023-01-11-03.00.13AM.csv
Full-Report-2023-01-10-02.00.43AM.csv
```

```
     try{
            $NameDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(0).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
            $latestFiles = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/$siteId/drives/$driveId/items/root/children?`$orderby=name desc&`$filter=startswith(name,'Full-Report-$NameDate ')&`$select=name,id&`$top=1" -Method GET -Headers $headers

        }catch{
            $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
            Write-Host "ERROR TYPE: $ErrorMessage"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if else condition to check for the size of the file. If the file has 0 bytes then you can skip it. For demonstration purpose I checked with a particular file which has 0 bytes. Below is the complete script that worked for me.

```
$response=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/$siteId/drives/$driveId/root:/Folder1:/children/sample.txt" -Method GET -Headers $headers
$object=$response.Content|ConvertFrom-Json
if($object.size -ne 0)
{
    $object."@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl"
}
}else{
    Write-Host "It is an Empty File"
}
```

***RESULTS:***

[image]

In your case, below is something that you can try.

```
$latestFiles = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/$siteId/drives/$driveId/items/root/children?`$orderby=name desc&`$filter=startswith(name,'Full-Report-$NameDate ')&`$select=name,id&`$top=1" -Method GET -Headers $headers
$object=$latestFiles.Content|ConvertFrom-Json
if($object.size -ne 0)
{
    <Download the file>
}
}else{
    Write-Host "It is an Empty File"
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for this but it look like it's not working and still downloading an empty file. I think there is no size in $object.size . please advice how to fix this issue.

Comment: @aasenomad Have you tried `ConvertFrom-Json` for the Invoke Request?